# How do I resize objects in my program?

Tags: java, swing

I'm still new to GUI development using Java Swing and right now I have a simple program with two JButtons, one JLabel and one JTextField. 
  [image: my program]

This is how it currently looks like and I want to resize all of the objects and initial size of the window when it is opened. How to achieve this? Below is my code.

```
public class Counter extends JFrame{

int counter = 0;
private final JTextField countText = new JTextField("0", 3);

public Counter(){
    super("Java Counter");

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JButton countUp = new JButton("Count up");
    countUp.addActionListener(new upListener());
    JButton countDown = new JButton("Count down"); 
    countDown.addActionListener(new downListener());
    countText.setEditable(false);
    content.add(countUp);
    content.add(new JLabel("Count is: "),countText);
    content.add(countDown);


    setContentPane(content);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: In which way do you want them to be resized ?

Comment: You need to resize the JFrame. Try the below:
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 25);

Comment: @Berger: I want to enlarge them, like making the window 3x bigger, buttons stays relatively the same but centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you out

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h)` or `setBounds(Rectangle r)`

x : axis x value
y : axis y value
w : width
h : height